# Show my activity (pop up) on incoming call screen

Tags: android, popup, phone-call

I want to make an app in which i want to call my activity and show 1 transparent box on incoming call screen. I have searched a lot but nothing is working.

Answer (score 1):

you must use following code to listening calling:

```
public class AutoAnswerIntentService extends BroadcastReceiver {
Context context = null;



private static final String TAG = "in reciver";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Toast.makeText(context, "calling now", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (!intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"))
        return;
    else {
        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            //Log.d(TAG , Ringing);

            return;
        } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {

            //Log.d(TAG, "CALL ANSWERED NOW");
            return;
        } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ALL DONE IN ELSE IF...... !!");

        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "ALL DONE IN ELSE ...... !!");

        }
    }
}
```

and in manifest file add following permission :

```
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But this code is not working. I have tried http://programminganswer.com/54544/popup-activity-upon-incoming-call-android.html also. But its also not working. Can you please provide me full code?

Comment: what your means this not working? what you tried? please post your manifest file and your code

Comment: Sure. I will share my code

Comment: Hello Shayan, I am not able to post my code here. Can we please communicate via mail. My email id is kushal.modi9@gmail.com.